# Is Quarkus 1.2.1 safe for AJP File Read / Inclusion (Ghostcat vulnerability)?

Tags: wildfly, redhat, quarkus, undertow

Is the solution applied in Quarkus?

Solution:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4851251

Problem:
https://its.ny.gov/security-advisory/multiple-vulnerabilities-red-hat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't use/expose AJP in Quarkus so you're safe on this side.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the AJP vulnerability would only be problematic if this port was publicly accessible.